# It works when it is debug mode, does not if it is normal running - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a listview and adapter in my class, i am inserting some values to db from another activity. Then I want to retrieve these values to my list in a tab page.

When I am running normally, i am taking an exception, I have checked my code and could not find any bug.

However, When i am running in debug mode, it works perfectly.

What is the problem here?

My sample code is as below

```
db = new DatabaseHandlerOn(getApplicationContext());
m_results = new ArrayList<On>();
this.m_adapter = new PlayedOn(this, R.layout.playedrowon, m_results);
this.setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);

sendNumbers2 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
            /*for(int i=15;i<55;i++)
            {
            db.addContact(new OnNumara(i+"","555",dateFormat.format(date),"1","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2",
                    "2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","55555555","0","0"));
            }*/
        playedOn = db.getAllContacts();

        for (On on : played) {
            m_results.add(on);
        }
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
};
Thread thread = new Thread(sendNumbers2, "sendNumbers2");
thread.start();

m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PlayedOnActivity.this,
        "", getString(R.string.PleaseWait), true);
m_ProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Logs:

```
11-05 14:10:03.839: E/AndroidRuntime(15958): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I do not understand if there is a null pointer exception, it should also be given in debug mode.

Comment: Show the code you wrote and also the exception message.

Comment: Please add the complete exception and the line/statement where the NullPointerException is happening.

Comment: it is occuring inside sendNumbers2 runnable